# R : Create and transform a dataframe based on existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My original question was poorly defined and confusing. Here it is again with extraneous columns removed for clarity and additional background.

My end game is to create a forced network graph using networkD3. To do this I need two dataframes. 
The first dataframe (dfNodes) lists each node in the graph and its grouping.  Volt, Miata and Prius are cars, so they get the group value of 1. 
Crusader is a bus so it is in group 3. Etc.

dfNodes dataframe:

```
id  name       group
0     vehicle   0
1     car       1
2     truck     2
3     bus       3
4     volt      1
5     miata     1
6     prius     1
7     tahoe     2
8     suburban  2
9     crusader  3
```

From this dataframe I need to construct the dataframe dfLinks to provide the linkages between nodes. It must look like:

dfLinks dataframe:

```
source  target
0           4
0           5
0           6
0           7
0           8
0           9
1           4
1           5
1           6
2           7
2           8
3           9
```

This shows the following:
**vehicle** is linked to volt, miata, prius, tahoe, suburban, crusader (they are all vehicles). (0, 4; 0, 5...0, 9)
**car** is linked to volt, miata, prius  (1, 4; 1, 5; 1, 6)
**truck** is linked to tahoe, suburban (2, 7 ; 2, 8)
**bus** is linked to crusader  (3, 9)

It may appear strange to link `vehicle-->model name (volt...crusader)--> type (car/bus/truck)` instead of 
`vehicle--> type -->  model name`
but that is the form that I need for my graph.

Comment: Is your actual dataset like this, where you have a number of categories in the first few rows (vehicle, car, etc.) and then the rest is individual car info?  Looks to me like the bottom section (rows 5-10) of the two datasets contain exactly the same info with different column names/order, so mostly you need to make the `vehicle` part of the second dataset and `rbind` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the criteria for creating the second dataframe; for example 'car' appears three times in the second data frame but is present four times in the first data frame? If you can provide more precise details about the transformation I can try and help more, but my first suggestion would be to look at the melt() and cast() functions in the reshape package:
http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html

Comment: Thanks Phil. I edited my problem to state it more clearly. I will also look into melt() and cast() functions as you suggest.  I appreciate you taking the time to offer advice.

Comment: No worries. I think most of the links (car > prius, for example) aren't too bad because you have an id that links the two. Vehicle is more problematic because there's no way to link to model name but exclude type. I think you would need to add these categories to the dataframe to automate this solution, or if a manual solution is acceptable write a short .R script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the replies from Phil and aosmith I revisited my question again. I have the luxury of creating the source dataframe (dfNodes) so I approached the problem from further upstream, first by creating dfNodes by combining dataframes, then creating dfLinks independently from dfNodes instead of based on dfNodes.  I feel my approach is very much a kludge but it does give me the result I am looking for.  Here is the code.  Other approaches, advice and criticism welcomed!  As you can tell, I am new to R.

`# Separate dataframes for the different categories of data
    vehicle    <- data.frame(source=0, name="vehicle", group=0)
    carGroup   <- data.frame(source=1, name="car", group=1)
    truckGroup <- data.frame(source=2, name="truck", group=2)
    busGroup   <- data.frame(source=3, name="bus", group=3)
    cars <- data.frame(source=c(4,5,6),
                       name=c("volt", "miata", "prius"), 
                       group=c(1,1,1))
    trucks <- data.frame(source=c(7,8),
                         name=c("tahoe", "suburban"),
                         group=c(2,2))
    buses <- data.frame(source=9,
                        name="crusader",
                        group=3)
    # 1. Build the dfNodes dataframe
    dfNodes <- rbind(vehicle, carGroup, truckGroup, busGroup, cars, trucks, buses)
    names(dfNodes)[1]<-"id"
    dfNodes

    # 2. Build dfLinks dataframe. Only source and target columns needed
    # Bind Vehicle to the 3 different vehicle dataframes
    vehicleToCars   <- cbind(vehicle, cars)
    vehicleToTrucks <- cbind(vehicle, trucks)
    vehicleToBuses  <- cbind(vehicle, buses)
    # Bind the Vehicle Groups to the vehicles
    carGroupToCars     <- cbind(carGroup, cars)
    truckGroupToTrucks <- cbind(truckGroup, trucks)
    busGroupToBuses    <- cbind(busGroup, buses)
    # Stack into the final dfLinks dataframe
    dfLinks <- rbind(vehicleToCars, vehicleToTrucks, vehicleToBuses,
                    carGroupToCars, truckGroupToTrucks, busGroupToBuses)
    names(dfLinks)[4]<-"target"
    dfLinks`